# Building an MSI for a project in a separate solution

Tags: windows-installer, solution

Currently I have a solution with 3 projects in them and 3 MSI installers in them. I was wondering how to separate the solutions so I could have the installers in their own solution.

When ever I pull the installers into there own solution none of the data can be found or referenced.

I was wonder what would be the best option to go about for creating an MSI installer in a separate solution?

Answer (score 1):

Once you split the projets into multiple solutions you can no longer use project references.  Not a bad thing but you need to be aware of it.  I actually like it this way.

Basically I'd suggest using a postbuild xcopy type command or other technique to deploy the application solution build output to a staging area that mocks the deployed environment.  And then use this directory to consume in your installer projects.